# iOS App communicates with Firebase, can Raspberry Pi communicate with the same Database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi, communication

I am working on a private iOS app, I can use for my smart home. I write the app using swift. The app communicates with a realtime database from Firebase. I would now like to write a program for a Raspberry Pi, that sends data to the same realtime database so it can communicate with my iOS app. Is this possible? Can a Raspberry Pi access the same database as an iOS App?

Comment: If you can't find an SDK/library for Pi that supports the Firebase Realtime Database you can always use its REST API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so it is possible to implement the same database in an iOS project and a python project?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime Database has a [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) that is callable from almost any platform, as you can access it by sending HTTP requests to the server.

For [Python](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) there are also SDKs, which are typically easier to work with than the REST API.

No matter which API/SDK you use to access the realtime database, all code accessing the same project (i.e. the same database URL) will be reading/writing the same database.